# Transform and Transfer 5 TB data from one marklogic server to another marklogic server

Tags: apache-spark, xquery, apache-nifi, marklogic, marklogic-corb

I have a scenario to transform and transfer 5 TB of data from one MarkLogic 4 database to another MarkLogic 10 database.

What are the best tools available to perform this action?

I have millions of files to transform and transfer. I need to change XML elements names while moving to new server.

I have found below tools. Could someone please suggest which is the best performing tool for this task?

1. CORB
2. MarkLogic Connector for Apache Spark
3. Apache NIFI
4. MLCP

Can someone please suggest what are best possible options are available, especially with apache spark?

Comment: CORB operates on single connection, so I doubt it will work here. I'd try MLCP, export data somewhere and import it in new server. Second idea would be to upgrade ML4 to ML10 and do backup restore

Comment: @Kamil Budziewski - I'm not sure what you mean by CoRB only working on a single connection. I'm assuming you mean that it's typically configured to only connect to a single cluster and talk via XCC, but that doesn't preclude you from either connecting to the other cluster and making HTTP calls in the process module, or plugging in your own Java task that also connects to the other cluster via XCC.

Comment: @KamilBudziewski I need to transform data while transferring from old to new server. Whether MLCP support data transformation?